# AspNet Identity - Custom IdentityRoleClaim & IdentityUserRole & IdentityUserClaim that duplicated foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, ef-fluent-api

currently, I am using AspNetCore and the configuration dbcontext as below:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, ApplicationRoleClaim, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }
```

So I would like to customize AspNetIdentity, but for simplicity I have just configured foreign key between tables:

- ApplicationUser is derived from IdentityUser
- ApplicationRole is derived from IdentityRole
- ApplicationUserClaim is derived from IdentityUserClaim`<string>`
- ApplicationUserRole is derived from IdentityUserRole`<string>`
- ApplicationRoleClaim is derived from IdentityRoleClaim`<string>`

---

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
     public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<ApplicationRoleClaim> RoleClaims { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<string>
{
     public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
     public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

---

And follows as are derived class implement IEntityTypeConfiguration for particular custom identity model.

```
public class ApplicationUserEntityBuilder : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
    {
        // still use default table name
        builder.ToTable("AspNetUsers");

        builder.Property(p => p.Id)
               .HasColumnType("CHAR(36)");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ApplicationRoleEntityBuilder : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRole>
 {
     public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationRole> builder)
     {
         // still use default table name
         builder.ToTable("AspNetRoles");
     }

 }
```

---

```
 public class ApplicationUserClaimEntityBuilder : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUserClaim>
  {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUserClaim> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(p => p.UserId)
                   .HasColumnName(nameof(ApplicationUserClaim.UserId))
                   .HasColumnType("CHAR(36)");

            builder.HasOne(p => p.User)
                   .WithMany(u => u.UserClaims)
                   .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId)
                   .IsRequired();
        }

    }
```

---

```
public class ApplicationUserRoleEntityBuilder : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUserRole>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUserRole> builder)
    {

        // still use default table name
        builder.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        builder.Property(p => p.Id)
               .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.HasOne(p => p.Role)
               .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
               .HasForeignKey(p => p.RoleId)
               .IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne(p => p.User)
               .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
               .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId)
               .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ApplicationRoleClaimEntityBuilder : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRoleClaim>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationRoleClaim> builder)
    {
        // still use default table name
        builder.ToTable("AspNetRoleClaims");

        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);

        builder.Property(p => p.Id)
               .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(p => p.RoleId)
               .HasColumnName(nameof(ApplicationRoleClaim.RoleId))
               .HasColumnType("CHAR(36)");

        builder.HasOne(p => p.Role)
               .WithMany(r => r.RoleClaims)
               .HasForeignKey(p => p.RoleId)
               .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

---

After these all fluent API configuration, EF Core generated duplicate Foreign Key in table AspNetRoleClaims, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserRoles

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(type: "CHAR(36)", nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    RoleId1 = table.Column<string>(nullable: true) // DUPLICATE
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoleClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId1",
                        column: x => x.RoleId1,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });


migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "CHAR(36)", nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    UserId1 = table.Column<string>(nullable: true) //DUPLICATE
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId1",
                        column: x => x.UserId1,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });


migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    RoleId1 = table.Column<string>(nullable: true), //DUPLICATE
                    UserId1 = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)  //DUPLICATE
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
                    table.UniqueConstraint("AK_AspNetUserRoles_Id", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId1",
                        column: x => x.RoleId1,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId1",
                        column: x => x.UserId1,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });
```

Please review it for me if anythings I did wrong. Thank you guys in advance.

---

**UPDATE 1**

Because of Navigation Property that causes duplicate foreign key. If I remove these properties in custom identity model that EFCore will not generate "DuplicateProperty1". So what I have to do now?

---

**FINAL UPDATE**

Root cause that I put `base.OnModelCreating(builder);` at the end of method `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)`. Therefore, anythings I have configured inner derived classes implemented IEntityTypeConfiguration that will be override by base class. And final version as below:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, ApplicationRoleClaim, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        var entitiesBuilder = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                      .GetTypes()
                                      .Where(type => type.ContainsGenericParameters == false && type.GetInterface(nameof(IEntityBuilder)) != null)
                                      .ToList();

        foreach (var entityBuilder in entitiesBuilder)
        {
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(entityBuilder) as IEntityBuilder;
            instance.RunConfiguration(builder);
        }

        // base.OnModelCreating(builder); move this line to the beginning of this method
    }
}
```

Comment: which versions of .net core and identity you use?

Comment: I am using asp.net core 2.1.5 and entityframework core  is 2.1.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relationships between tables are already set inside *Identity's* `IdentityDbContext` [default configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-model-configuration). That means you don't have to specify them explicitly (using navigational props / fluent api configuration).

However, it looks like you want to have Guid/Uuid instead of string as a column type for your Primary/Foreign keys. If that's the case, the proper way to achieve that is to use generic variants of classes you've already inherited.

For example, you can define only classes you need to expand and add additional properties to them - which will be included into DB Migration:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
}
```

In addition to that, your `DbContext` must inherit proper variant of `IdentityDbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationUserDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
{
}
```

After that, your migration will generate a script to change PK/FKs into proper column type. If you need to expand other types from *Identity*, you can use most generic variant of `IdentityDbContext` which takes a bunch of [type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext-8?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: yeah, thank you for your point. The reason that I put the line code base.OnModelCreating(builder) at the end of method. So that the base class overrode anything I had configured. Details in Final Update. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you inherit from identity models it already has this relations and other properties specified. Your code just added additional relations between entities. You can read more about identity customization in documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: thank you for your point, I have just updated in Final Update. You could see details that I fixed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configure the `IEntityTypeConfiguration` like below in `AppDbContext`.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, ApplicationRoleClaim, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserEntityBuilder());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationRoleEntityBuilder());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserClaimEntityBuilder());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserRoleEntityBuilder());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationRoleClaimEntityBuilder());
    }
}
```

Comment: of course I have configured to run ApplyConfiguration so that EF Core generate a script migration. Anyways, thank you :)